# Difference between a==a?a:b and a?a:b

Tags: javascript

Both are the same. So what is the difference between them?

```js
let a=NaN;
let b=2.2
console.log(a==a?a:b);
console.log(a?a:b);
```

Comment: No, a=0 would produce different results.

Comment: Could you please provide the reason of negative vote.

Comment: Maybe you should do a bit research on MDN before asking here.

Comment: This is a basic programming logic. Having such a reputation does not suit you to ask such question @RameshRajendran

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, I would disagree, this is something related to JavaScript and loosely typed languages, however I agree that with he should do more research before asking here.

Comment: My main question is how it wokring when using NaN

Comment: @RameshRajendran, no it was not, you just changed it to NaN, if the history is correct of course, you are kinda rude to the ppl trying to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *first* statement will return always `true` except the case when `a` is `NaN`

> Why `NaN == NaN` returns false ?

Because the JS spec [says so](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6):

> - If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>   - If x is NaN, return false.
>   - If y is NaN, return false.

The *second* statement will return `true` only if `a` is not a `falsy` variable.

When I say `falsy` i mean *undefined*, *null* , *0*, *''*. A **falsy** value is a value that *translates* to false when evaluated in a *Boolean* context.

[**Truthy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

[**Falsy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy):

> A falsy value is a value that translates to false when evaluated in a Boolean context.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yupe. I have changed it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

a==a returns a boolean whereas 
a is just a number.

a==a is always true whereas a is true ( can be so called ) only if a is non 0

---------------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------

In your code put a = 0 you will see the difference

Comment: What?? Am confused with your asnwer.

Comment: a==a returns always returns true. in ternary operator

Comment: a==a //true, this selects which ever is true

Comment: ternary operator returns based on value of a, if a is non zero similar to true else similar to false